# Avoiding the re-evaluation of a RegionPlot3D

Tags: plotting

Is there a simple way to save the output from `RegionPlot3D` so as to avoid re-evaluating when the notebook is re-opened and `Show` is used to re-display the plot? The re-evaluation takes in excess of 30 mins of run time.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you don't delete the graphic before you save the Notebook it should be there the next time you open it, without a long delay.  Why doesn't that work for you?

Answer (score 5):

One way is to give your figure a name:

```
 sav = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^3 - z^2 > 0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Then save it:

```
 DumpSave["temp.mx", sav]
```

To read it back in later (after clearing everything or restarting the program)

```
 DumpGet["temp.mx"]
```

This should work to avoid recalculation of most anything, not just RegionPlot.

Comment: Thanks bill s ... your suggestion works like a charm. ron m

Comment: Oops. Just when I thought my RegionPlot3D save issue was resolved, I encountered a problem when transferring the notebook from my desktop to my laptop. Here's what happen:

Comment: After running a RegionPlot3d named testplot on my desktop, I saved it using DumpSave["testplot.mx"], then saved the notebook, quit Mathematica, copied notebook to my laptop, opened it and then tried to retrieve the plot by using DumpGet["testplot.mx"] but this failed. The plot took 60 mins of run time, and would take even longer on my laptop. The procedure I followed must be incorrect because I am certain this simple transfer can be done successfully allowing me to open the plot on my laptop without re-running. Does anyone have any suggestions. Thanks. ron m

Comment: If the read (DumpGet) failed then the path is probably wrong... figure out what your default directory is and put it there, or else change the directory.